# Proper way to include JS files with Sage WordPress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dependencies

From [the doc](https://roots.io/sage/docs/theme-development-and-building/) I can't figure out the right way to include my JS files into Sage theme. What's the correct procedure for this?

Answer (score 4):

### Including custom script (not installed via bower package manager)

You can use `scripts/**/*` glob pattern. This will bundle all scripts that are inside `assets/scripts/` directory into `dist/scripts/main.js` file.

Edit your `assets/manifest.json` like this:

```
{ 
  "dependencies": {
    "main.js": {
      "vendor": [
        // Your external libs that are not available via bower
      ]
      "files": [
        "scripts/**/*",
        "scripts/main.js"
      ],
      "main": true
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

- `vendor` - property paths are relative to your project root
- `files` - property is relative to your `assets` folder

For more info visit some [examples](https://github.com/austinpray/asset-builder/blob/master/help/examples.md).

### Installing & including bower dependency

For example, let's install carousel [Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) library.

1. Install library via bower

   ```
   bower install --save slick-carousel
   ```
2. Next you need to tell which files do you need from installed package. So you need add paths of those files to `overrides` section of `bower.json` file.

**NOTE:** Paths are relative to `/bower_components/<package_name>`.

```
    "slick-carousel": {
      "main": [
        "./slick/slick.min.js",
        "./slick/slick.css"
       ]
    }
```

Now library will be part of compiled dist/scripts/main.js file.

Comment: This is partly working for me but i can't seem to call functions from main.js when the function is in myscripts.js. I also have to have (function($) { //all code with jq// })(jQuery);  otherwise get the usual '$ is nota  function'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://discourse.roots.io/t/how-does-sage-9-enqueue-jquery/11239/8

Answer (score -1):

You need to add code to functions.php file. You will see there sage_sripts or similar function and within that function you will need to add wp_enqueue_script

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Here is a sample:

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function sage_scripts() {

    $scripts_version = 1;

    wp_enqueue_style( 'sage-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'yourscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/yourscript.js', array(), '1', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sage_scripts' );
```

Answer (score -3):

I haven't used this particular theme, but most likely there is a "custom javascript" box where you can insert your javascript. If you prefer to keep your javascript in files as opposed to copy-pasted into your theme, the answer is a bit more complicated.

I appreciate the way the Genesis Framework does it. Instead of a box for javascript they give a box for inserting any content you want (meta tags, styles, scripts) into the head of the theme.

You could also load a file through your theme's functions.php using wp_enqueue_script(). The problem here is that you can no longer (easily) update your theme, because the process would overwrite the changes to the file. You do not want to miss a single update for security reasons.

[That's why I recommend a solution like this -](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/)  a quick and easy plugin for inserting script files into the document. You get the files into your theme, and you no one can accidently overwrite or delete your changes later.