# Sage wordpress template broken trying to add Bower dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, bower

EDIT:

So everything below this edit block was my initial issue, which I have now fixed and spawned another issue. Argh. I was initially breaking the manifest.json file by commenting out a few lines of code with '//'.

Now that issue is out of the way, I am getting this error:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

My manifest.json file is pointing at...

```
"config": {
"devUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

and I've changed absolutely nothing else.

Upon running gulp --watch a new tab is not automatically being opened in the browser, yet my site is accessible from localhost/wordpress.

So confused.

/ EDIT.

I am currently building a Wordpress website using the Sage template. Today I have been trying to add the Slick Carousel plugin using Bower.

I used the CLI to add it to the bower.json file and it initially worked, except I was getting '.slick is not a function' errors when trying to initialise. After inspecting the sources tab in chrome, I could see that the slick.js files were being loaded after main.js, so started moving a few things about in the manifest.json file.

Now the whole build is broken and I'm not able to access the site at localhost:3000, nor can I access browserSync at localhost:3001. I've compared both the bower.json and manifest.json to the base files and they are the same - minus some alterations to devUrl in manifest.json, and the addition of overrides in bower.json.

I'm really stuck in a rut here, it feel's like I've completely destroyed my whole project and I have no idea how to remedy it. I've been aimlessly staring at the screen for about 3 hours now.

The errors I get in the build log are as follows:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
at Object.parse (native)
at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sage-8.4.2/node_modules/asset-builder/lib/readManifest.js:19:15)
at new module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sage-8.4.2/node_modules/asset-builder/lib/Manifest.js:28:34)
at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sage-8.4.2/node_modules/asset-builder/index.js:17:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sage-8.4.2/gulpfile.js:24:40)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

What on earth have I done wrong!?

Comment: "devUrl" should reflect your local development hostname, for example `http://localhost/wordpress`.To initialises BrowserSync run `gulp watch`

Comment: Yeah I've tried it as above, and as http://localhost:3000, no luck either way.

I am no longer getting the:
    [BS] Proxying: http://localhost:3000
    [BS] Access URL's:

Messages when i run gulp watch, the final message is just 'Finished 'build' after 2.97ms'.

It's super confusing because I've only altered things in the manifest.json and bower.json files, and they now reflect their original states.

Comment: It may be heresy to suggest it, but try completely deleting and reinstalling your node_modules and bower_components directories. At least you'll be starting fresh - you won't lose anything if package.json and bower.json include your dependencies. This may fix something that you inadvertently changed.

Comment: Re: slick carousel, have you seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38595670/3590673